# In Spark dataframe how to Transpose rows to columns?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

this may be a very simple question. I want to transpose all the rows of dataframe to columns. I want to convert this df as shown below output DF. What are the ways in spark to achieve this?

Note : I have single column in input DF

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._
val df = Seq(("row1"), ("row2"), ("row3"), ("row4"), ("row5")).toDF("COLUMN_NAME")
df.show(false)

    Input DF:
    +-----------+
    |COLUMN_NAME|
    +-----------+
    |row1       |
    |row2       |
    |row3       |
    |row4       |
    |row5       |
    +-----------+

    Output DF
    +----+----+----+----+----+
    |row1|row2|row3|row4|row5|
    +----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe)

Comment: Think this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49393080/1125159. It's not clear if you want row1, row2. etc to be column names in the output DataFrame.  I'm guessing not, so you should update your question to include the desired column names.

Comment: Without ```groupBy```, ```pivot```, ```agg```, & ```first``` ..check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686883/scala-spark-flatten-array-of-key-value-structs/61733898#61733898

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you  ?

```
df.withColumn("group",monotonicallyIncreasingId  ).groupBy("group").pivot("COLUMN_NAME").agg(first("COLUMN_NAME")).show
```

Comment: This is creating row entries in the output DF