# pyspark pivot alternative with better performance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pivot, databricks, crosstab

Below is my input dataset :

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([ \
    ("0","CattyCat","B2K","B"), \
    ("0","CattyCat","B3L","I"), \
    ("0","CattyCat","B3U","I"), \
    ("0","CattyCat","D3J","C"), \
    ("0","CattyCat","J1N","H"), \
    ("0","CattyCat","K7A","I"), \
    ("0","CattyCat","L1B","D"), \
    ("0","CattyCat","U3F","B"), \
    ("1","CattyCat","B2K","I"), \
    ("1","CattyCat","B3L","I"), \
    ("1","CattyCat","B3U","I"), \
    ("1","CattyCat","D3J","C"), \
    ("1","CattyCat","J1N","H"), \
    ("1","CattyCat","K7A","I"), \
    ("1","CattyCat","L1B","D"), \
    ("1","CattyCat","U3F","B"), \
    ("2","CattyCat","B2K","B"), \
    ("2","CattyCat","B3L","B"), \
    ("2","CattyCat","B3U","I"), \
    ("2","CattyCat","D3J","C"), \
    ("2","CattyCat","J1N","H"), \
    ("2","CattyCat","K7A","I"), \
    ("2","CattyCat","L1B","D"), \
    ("2","CattyCat","U3F","B"), \
], ["RowCount","CatName","Name","Value"])

df.show(30)

+--------+--------+----+-----+
|RowCount| CatName|Name|Value|
+--------+--------+----+-----+
|       0|CattyCat| B2K|    B|
|       0|CattyCat| B3L|    I|
|       0|CattyCat| B3U|    I|
|       0|CattyCat| D3J|    C|
|       0|CattyCat| J1N|    H|
|       0|CattyCat| K7A|    I|
|       0|CattyCat| L1B|    D|
|       0|CattyCat| U3F|    B|
|       1|CattyCat| B2K|    I|
|       1|CattyCat| B3L|    I|
|       1|CattyCat| B3U|    I|
|       1|CattyCat| D3J|    C|
|       1|CattyCat| J1N|    H|
|       1|CattyCat| K7A|    I|
|       1|CattyCat| L1B|    D|
|       1|CattyCat| U3F|    B|
|       2|CattyCat| B2K|    B|
|       2|CattyCat| B3L|    B|
|       2|CattyCat| B3U|    I|
|       2|CattyCat| D3J|    C|
|       2|CattyCat| J1N|    H|
|       2|CattyCat| K7A|    I|
|       2|CattyCat| L1B|    D|
|       2|CattyCat| U3F|    B|
+--------+--------+----+-----+
```

My goal is to pivot\cross-tab this data. I was able to acheve this using groupby.pivot.agg as below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
display(df.groupBy("RowCount","CatName").pivot("Name").agg(F.first("value")))

+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| RowCount | CatName  | B2K | B3L | B3U | D3J | J1N | K7A | L1B | U3F |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 0        | CattyCat | B   | I   | I   | C   | H   | I   | D   | B   |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 1        | CattyCat | I   | I   | I   | C   | H   | I   | D   | B   |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2        | CattyCat | B   | B   | I   | C   | H   | I   | D   | B   |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

But the problem that I'm facing is that when the dataset is huge(100's of millions), the performance is very very poor. (Single task in the last stage of a single executor, stuck for hours)
P.S: I did also find out that pivot could also take a second parameter which could be a sequence of column names which might offer better performance. But unfortunately I cannot know these column names in advance.

Is there a way of doing this 'Cross Tab' in a better performant way ?

Comment: You can check this post - without ```pivot``` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686883/scala-spark-flatten-array-of-key-value-structs/61733898#61733898 .. its in scala

Comment: Thanks will check it out. Have to try converting this to pyspark